# Reshape data in R: transpose

Tags: r, transpose

How can I reshape the following data in R so that it is organized in rows?

```
1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
```

should become:

```
1 0 0
1 0 0
0 1 0
```

Thanks

Comment: Also these are almost similar . [How to turn a vector into a matrix in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614946/how-to-turn-a-vector-into-a-matrix-in-r) and [How to convert a single column to a matrix in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439531/how-to-convert-a-single-column-to-a-matrix-in-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `matrix` with the `byrow` argument

```
matrix(v1, 3, 3, byrow=TRUE)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    0    0
#[2,]    1    0    0
#[3,]    0    1    0
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
```